# How do you pass PHP variables from a page to a modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm building a website, using Laravel and Bootstrap, that contains a table of books posted by the user. The code for the table is shown below:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-md-3">Title</th>
        <th class="col-md-3">Author</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">Price</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">Courses</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">Date Added</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">More Info</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="searchable">
        @foreach($books as $book)
            <tr>
            <td>{{$book->title}}</td>
            <td>{{$book->author}}</td>
            <td>${{$book->price}}</td>
            <td>{{$book->course_code}}</td>
            <td>{{$book->added_on}}</td>
            <td><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{$book->id}}" href="#more_info" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</button></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The button in each row of the table opens up a modal that displays more information about the book. The book's information gets passed into the modal using Javascript. Here's the code for the modal:

```
<div class = "modal fade" id = "more_info" role = "dialog">
    <div class = "modal-dialog">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <h4 id="book_title">Title</h4>
                <h5 id="book_author">Author</h5>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                <p id="book_price">Price: </p>
                <p id="book_school">School: </p>
                <p id="book_course_code">Course(s): </p>
                <p id="book_date">Added On: </p>
                <p>Description:<br></p>
                <p id="book_description">Description<br></p>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-footer">
                <a class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
                <input type="hidden" name="book_id" id="book_id" value=""/>
                <button class = "btn btn-primary" data-dismiss = "modal" href="#contact_seller" data-toggle="modal">Contact Seller</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a button on the bottom right of modal that would call upon another modal to contact the seller of the book. I only want the button to appear if the user is not authenticated, or if the book does not belong to the authenticated user.

How do I approach this?

The main issue that I'm facing is passing the book id into the modal as a PHP variable so I can just use this code:

```
@if(Auth::guest() or Auth::user()->id != Book::where('id','%'.book_id.'%')->first()->user_id)
    <td><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{$book->id}}" href="#more_info" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</button></td>
@endif
```

But I'm not sure how to do that.

---

### Edit:

As for the Javascript portion, the books' information first gets stored in a Javascript object, which is included at the beginning of the same file that table is in:

```
<script>
    var appVariables = {};
    appVariables.books = {!! $books->keyBy('id') !!};
</script>
```

It will then include the Javascript file that contains the code that will use the object we just created to transfer the book contents to the modal according to its id:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#more_info').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var id = button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var book = appVariables.books[id]; //fetching the contents of book according to id received

      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('#book_title').text(book.title)
      modal.find('#book_author').text("By " + book.author)
      modal.find('#book_price').text("Price: $" + book.price)
      modal.find('#book_school').text("School: " + book.school)
      modal.find('#book_course_code').text("Course(s): " + book.course_code)
      modal.find('#book_date').text("Added On: " + book.added_on)
      modal.find('#book_description').text(book.description)
      modal.find('#book_id').text(book.id)
   })
});
```

Comment: where is the javascript part? in the same view file or different view file?

Comment: It's in a different file. I'll just edit the question to include that.